# SimpleXMLIterator in PHP not traversing the XML tree in BFS-wise manner

Tags: php, xml, tree, iterator

I am trying to use `SimpleXMLIterator` in php version 5.6.11 to iterate over an XML tree in BFS order. However, what I am finding is that it just traverses the XML elements nested at level one just below the root node at level zero, skipping all nested elements at levels 2, 3, ... .

So how do I get the iterator to traverse the XML tree BFS-wise?

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php) mentions that the iterator is supposed to be *recursive*. Here is the code:

```
<?php

function getXMLCode() {

  $xmlCode = <<<XML
  <home>
    <livingroom>
      <sofa>
        <leftPillow></leftPillow>
        <rightPillow></rightPillow>
      </sofa>
      <television></television>
    </livingroom>
    <bedroom>
      <bed>
        <sheet></sheet>
        <duvet></duvet>
        <pillow></pillow>
      </bed>
    </bedroom>
    <bathroom>
      <sink></sink>
      <toilet></toilet>
      <bath>
        <bathtap></bathtap>
      </bath>
    </bathroom>
    <kitchen>
      <fridge>
        <lettuce>
          <snail></snail>
        </lettuce>
      </fridge>
    </kitchen>
  </home>
XML;

  return $xmlCode;

}

function test() {

  $xmlCode = getXMLCode();

  $simpleXMLIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlCode);

  foreach ($simpleXMLIterator as $xmlElement) {

    echo $xmlElement->getName(), "\n";

  }

}

test();
```

and here is the output, which, as described, does not constitute a BFS-traversal (plus the root node is omitted too):

OUTPUT:

```
livingroom
bedroom
bathroom
kitchen
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
home
livingroom
bedroom
bathroom
kitchen
sofa
television
bed
sink
toilet
bath
fridge
leftPillow
rightPillow
sheet
duvet
pillow
bathtap
lettuce
snail
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXmlIterator($xml),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach ($it as $key => $value){
    print(trim($key) . PHP_EOL);
}
```

http://ideone.com/5udHSg

Comment: Your answer only covers elements listed at level 2, but not level 3 elements such as _<snail>_. Could you please update your answer to include arbitrary nesting of XML elements?

Comment: I've tried your updated code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/hMyr2a) but it's not working for me.

Comment: I am stuck on the fact that I cannot seem to instantiate a SimpleXMLIterator from a SimpleXMLElement. At least I couldn't find any way to do so in the PHP documentation. If I could, then I could code a generic BFS algorithm. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I tried [your solution](http://ideone.com/6HS4pT) the elements at level 0 and 1 are missing. Plus I am trying a solution involving SimpleXMLIterator. [Here is what I have so far](http://ideone.com/83nZ90).

Comment: Top level is always omitted from these, so you will never get `home`. Wrap that one level deeper if you need it. _Usually_ you know what the top level is though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's true, the top level is omitted. But I need some code that works with arbitrary levels, not just three. Thanks.

Comment: One more try, I think I got it now. I had forgotten to add the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` option. I updated the ideone as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very much appreciated. The only thing is that your traversal is a DFS traversal (depth-first), whereas I was looking for a BFS traversal (bredth-first), and have posted it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [following code](http://ideone.com/hxGEoT) traverses the XML tree BFS-style using SimpleXMLIterator which is what the question originally asked. Unfortunately it seems that the root element cannot be output using SimpleXMLIterator because of the way SimpleXMLElement is designed.

```
<?php

function getXMLCode() {

  $xmlCode = <<<XML
  <home>
    <livingroom>
      <sofa>
        <leftPillow></leftPillow>
        <rightPillow></rightPillow>
      </sofa>
      <television></television>
    </livingroom>
    <bedroom>
      <bed>
        <sheet></sheet>
        <duvet></duvet>
        <pillow></pillow>
      </bed>
    </bedroom>
    <bathroom>
      <sink></sink>
      <toilet></toilet>
      <bath>
        <bathtap></bathtap>
      </bath>
    </bathroom>
    <kitchen>
      <fridge>
        <lettuce>
          <snail></snail>
        </lettuce>
      </fridge>
    </kitchen>
  </home>
XML;

  return $xmlCode;

}

function test() {

  $xmlCode = getXMLCode();

  $currentSimpleXMLIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlCode);

  $nonTraversedSimpleXMLIterators = array($currentSimpleXMLIterator);

  while (count($nonTraversedSimpleXMLIterators) > 0) {

    $currentSimpleXMLIterator = array_shift($nonTraversedSimpleXMLIterators);

    for ($currentSimpleXMLIterator->rewind(); $currentSimpleXMLIterator->valid(); $currentSimpleXMLIterator->next()) {

      if ($currentSimpleXMLIterator->hasChildren()) {

        $childSimpleXMLIterator = $currentSimpleXMLIterator->getChildren();

        array_push($nonTraversedSimpleXMLIterators, $childSimpleXMLIterator);

      }

      echo $currentSimpleXMLIterator->current()->getName(), "\n";

    }

  }

}

test();
```

OUTPUT:

```
livingroom
bedroom
bathroom
kitchen
sofa
television
bed
sink
toilet
bath
fridge
leftPillow
rightPillow
sheet
duvet
pillow
bathtap
lettuce
snail
```